# How can I make my thumbnails render well?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm genereating [image thumbnails in a list](http://koolbusiness.com/india) but they do not come out perfect.

[image]

As can be seen from the screenshot, thumbnails may exceed the designated area. I tried setting a somewhat smaller size for the thumbnail but it's still not placing itself well. What can I do? The code that renders the thumbnails looks like:

`<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zIWGDBEuLiqUHkN4uEfx4WprFfeSE4hnWrxLYIk_VdKYuCWYgR5ZmGFEIQXv1nYNEv1DWlq_jcMrJ6biSnGWJwFnwsQ=s80" title="Royal Info Service Offered" alt="Royal Info Service Offered">`

The parameter `s80` is the image size and I probably can't make it smaller. Should I change the CSS? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a `max-height: 62px;` on the image.

I recommend giving the image a class of thumbnail as follows:

**html**

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zIWGDBEuLiqUHkN4uEfx4WprFfeSE4hnWrxLYIk_VdKYuCWYgR5ZmGFEIQXv1nYNEv1DWlq_jcMrJ6biSnGWJwFnwsQ=s80" title="Royal Info Service Offered" alt="Royal Info Service Offered">
```

and applying the max height css to that class:

**css**

```
.thumbnail {
  max-height: 62px;
}
```